# How to show $\partial_t \hat g = \sigma'(t)\psi_t^* (g) + \sigma(t) \psi_t^*(\partial_t g) + \sigma(t) \psi_t^*(L_Xg)$?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

$X(t)$  is a time dependent family of smooth vector fields on $M$, and $\psi_t$ is the local flow of $X(t)$, namely for any smooth $f:M\rightarrow R$
$$
X(\psi_t(y),t) f = \frac{\partial(f\circ \psi_t)}{\partial t} (y)
$$
Let
$$
\hat g(t) =\sigma(t) \psi_t^*(g(t))
$$
How to show
$$
\partial_t \hat g = \sigma'(t)\psi_t^* (g) + \sigma(t) \psi_t^*(\partial_t g) 
+ \sigma(t) \psi_t^*(L_Xg)
$$
where $L_Xg$ is Lie derivative. I think it is equal to show
$$
\partial _t (\psi_t^*(g(t))) =  \psi_t^*(\partial_t g) 
+  \psi_t^*(L_Xg)
$$
but I don't know how to show it. I feel calculate $\partial_t \psi_t^*$ is the key point. But seemly, it is hard to represent it.

What I know about Lie derivative :
$$
L_Xg(p) =\lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{\psi_t^*(g(\psi_t(p)))  - g(p)}{t}
$$

PS: This problem is from the Proposition 1.2.1 of Topping's Lectures on the Ricci flow. Topping's hint:
$$
\psi_t^*(g(t))=\psi_t^*(g(t)-g(s))+\psi_t^*(g(s))
$$
and differentiate at $t=s$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am recently reading Peter topping’s book and I follow the hint in the book to give an explanation. I will only give the calculation of the difficult part in your problem, the left is quite easy and you just need to combine all of them. First have
$$\frac{\partial\hat{g}}{\partial t}=\sigma'(t)\psi^*_t(g)+\sigma(t)(\psi^{*}_t(g(t)))'$$.
We then write
\begin{equation}
   \psi_t^*(g(t))=\psi^*_t(g(t)-g(s))+\psi_t^*(g(s)).
  \end{equation}
Thus we differentiate at $t=s$, and obtain
\begin{equation}
   \begin{aligned}
    \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\bigg|_{t=s} \psi_t^*(g(t))
    &=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\bigg|_{t=s}\psi^*_t(g(t)-g(s))+\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\bigg|_{t=s}\psi^*_t(g(s)) \\
    &= \lim_{t\rightarrow s}\frac{\psi^*_t(g(t)-g(s))-\psi^*_s(0)}{t-s}+\lim_{t\rightarrow s}\frac{\psi^*_t(g(s))-\psi_s^*(g(s))}{t-s} \\
    &= \lim_{t\rightarrow s}\frac{\psi_t^*(g(t)-g(s))}{t-s}+\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{\psi^*_{t+s}g(s)-\psi_s^*(g(s))}{t} \\
    &=\psi^*_t(\frac{\partial g}{\partial t})\bigg|_{t=s}+\psi_s^*L_Xg(s)\\
    &=\psi^*_t(\frac{\partial g}{\partial t})\bigg|_{t=s}+\psi_t^*L_Xg(t)\bigg|_{t=s}.
   \end{aligned}
  \end{equation}
We notice that $s$ is arbitrary and finish the proof.  If you find any mistake, do tell me and we can have a further discussion since I just start studying the Ricci flow.

Comment: I have stopped studying  Ricci flow for a month since  the Spring Festival. Some things I've forgotten.  But  I feel your answer is right.  Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: I think we make a same mistake.  In fact, $\psi_t$ is not one-parameter transformation. And there is not $\psi_t^*\circ\psi_{\Delta t}^* = \psi_{t+\Delta t}^*$. There is a counterexample in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4531798/analogue-of-one-parameter-transformation-for-time-dependent-vector-field

Comment: No this doee not matter. It is an one-paremeter transformation definitely which can be proved similarly as the case for a fixed vector field.

Comment: I also have a look at your counter example, but I am not so clear with it. As I said, the is one parameter transformations exists for a small time interval due to ODE, in your counterter example you think time t=1,2,3 right? Maybe the time is too long comparing to the existence of ODE theorey.

Comment: The counter examle is alright (it can be changed to in small time).   I spend some time in An introduction to the manifold.    I am sure the method in Topping's book is wrong (Although there are many other book or paper have similiar  result).  The right result should be the Bryant's paper *Ricci flow solitons in dimension three with SO(3)-symmetries*.  The $\varphi_t$ should be changed to $\varphi_{h(t)}$.   But I still unfinish the detail of Bryant's paper (He gave no details).

Answer (score 2):

After some think, I have a flawed answer.

The diffeomorphisms $\psi_t$  of $X(t)$  satisfy
$$
\partial_t \psi_t(y) = X(t)(y), ~~~\psi_0(y)=y,~~~\forall y \in M 
\tag{1}
$$
Although the geometry of $\psi_t$ is complex for me, but I feel (1) has local existence, then by the compact of $M$, (1) should have global existence. But just feel, about this, I do not to read book now.

Therefore, for $f:M\rightarrow R$, I have
$$
X(t)(\psi_t(y))f = \frac{d}{dt}(f\circ \psi_t(y))
$$

Now, I have
$$
\partial_t \hat g(t) = \sigma'(t) \psi_t^*(g)
+\sigma(t) \psi_t^*(\partial_tg)
+ \sigma(t) (\partial_t\psi_t^*)(g)
$$
noticing $\psi_t^*$ is linear transformation, any linear transformation can be treated as time a matrix, therefore, it meet Leibniz/product rule.

Besides, since $\psi_t^*\circ\psi_{\Delta t}^* = \psi_{t+\Delta t}^*$I have
$$
 (\partial_t\psi_t^*)(g)=
\lim_{\Delta t \rightarrow 0}
\frac{\psi^*_{t+\Delta t} -\psi_t^*}{\Delta t}g
=
\psi_t^*(\lim_{\Delta t \rightarrow 0}
\frac{\psi^*_{\Delta t}(g) -g}{\Delta t})
=\psi_t^*(L_{X(0)}g)
$$
So, I have
$$
\partial_t \hat g(t) = \sigma'(t) \psi_t^*(g)
+\sigma(t) \psi_t^*(\partial_tg)
+ \sigma(t) \psi_t^*(L_{X(0)}g)
$$
Last, I am not sure whether  the Topping's $L_Xg$ is $L_{X(0)}g$.

PS: I am not sure about the global existence of (1) and the mean of $L_Xg$. If you know, please tell me, thanks.