# Analogue of one-parameter transformation for time dependent vector field

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

In the study of solitons of Ricci flow, we need to consider a time dependent vector field $X(t)$ and the generating diffeomorphisms $\psi: \mathbb R\times M \rightarrow M$  (for detail to read the 1.2 of *Lectures on the Ricci flow*). And denote $\psi_t(x)=\psi(t,x)$.

They satisfy that, for any smooth function $f:M\rightarrow \mathbb R$ (where $M$ is the smooth manifold),
$$
X(\psi_t(y),t)f =\frac{\partial f\circ \psi_t}{\partial t} (y)   ~~~~~~y\in M  \tag{1}
$$
Assuming we have a local coordinate such that
$$
f(x)=f(x^1,...,x^n)  \\
\psi_t(x) = (\psi_t^1(x),...,\psi_t^n(x)) \\
X(\psi_t(y),t) = X^i(\psi_t(y),t) \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}
$$
then, $(1)$ is equal to
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} (\psi_t(y)) \frac{\partial \psi_t^i}{\partial t}(y) = X^i(\psi_t(y), t) \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} (\psi_t(y))
$$
Therefore, the existence of $\psi_t$ is equal to the existence of
$$
\frac{\partial \psi_t^i}{\partial t}(y) =  X^i(\psi_t(y), t)  \tag{2}
$$
Although, I guess that $(2)$ may have not solution. But the key point is that I need
$$
\psi_a\circ\psi_b = \psi_{a+b}   \tag{3}
$$
for deal the below related problem. But obviously, $(1)$ is not the usual  one-parameter transformation, I don't know how to get $(3)$ ?

Related problem :   [How to show $\partial_t \hat g = \sigma'(t)\psi_t^* (g) + \sigma(t) \psi_t^*(\partial_t g) + \sigma(t) \psi_t^*(L_Xg)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4308471/how-to-show-partial-t-hat-g-sigmat-psi-t-g-sigmat-psi-t-pa)

**PS(a few hours late):** I've constructed a counterexample and write it in picture below. Where the $X_2(t)$ can be suitably choose. For example
$$
X_2(t) = (2-t) X_1 + (t-1) X_3
$$
The $X_1, X_2$ are the velocity fields on $S^2$ respect to angular velocity $1,-1$.  Obviously,
$$
\psi_3=id\ne \psi_1\circ\psi_1\circ\psi_1$$

> [image]

Comment: I am  really clever   ; )

Comment: Your question is basically an existence of ODE. We can always find such even the vector field is changing since it is a ODE.  Therefore we can always get the one paremeter transformations, but you need to notice this parameter transformations can only be defined on a small interval not on R due to the theory of ODE.  You may review the process of how we get $\phi_a\circ\phi_b=\phi_{a+b} to understand this.

Comment: Maybe you can refer to the book Hamilton’s Ricci flow.

Comment: @HONGHAOJIEYOU  Seemly, the Hamilton's Ricci flow (2005 version) doesn't explain the  existence of 1-parameter of $X$ and the process of $\phi_a\circ\phi_b=\phi_{a+b}$.   It said that if $X$ is a complete vector field, then $X$ generating a global 1-parameter group, but not prove.  I have few knowledge about ODE, only know about  separation of variables and so on.   Which book is suitable for learning the existence of global 1-parameter diffeomorphisms ?    Thanks your help.

Comment: Any books about manifolds. For example, An introduction to the manifold written by Loring W. Tu p155 for the second edition.

Comment: Moreover , the existence of A solution of ODE with initial value is well-known. Any ODE books will talk about it.