# Computing derivative of pullback of time-dependent metric

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors, lie-derivative, ricci-flow

$\qquad$ Following Topping's book on Ricci flow, $X(t)$ be a time-dependent collection of vector fields with associated collection of diffeomorphisms $\psi_t$ defined on a compact, closed manifold $M$. Given $g=g(t)$ a family of metrics on $M$, why is it that if we define $\hat{g}(t)=\sigma(t)\psi_t^*(g(t))$ ($\sigma$ a smooth, real valued function) that
$$\frac{\partial \hat{g}}{\partial t}=\sigma'(t)\psi_t^*(g(t))+\sigma(t)\psi_t^*\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial t}\right)+\sigma(t)\psi_t^*(\mathcal{L}_Xg)?$$

One definition of the Lie derivative I know is $\mathcal{L}_Xg=\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\big|_{t=0}\psi_t^*\right)g$, so directly using the product rule and this definition I get

$$\frac{\partial \hat{g}}{\partial t}=\sigma'(t)\psi_t^*(g(t))+\sigma(t)\psi_t^*\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial t}\right)+\sigma(t)\mathcal{L}_Xg.$$

Where is my mistake, or how do I see the first equation holds? I've looked at [How to show $\partial_t \hat g = \sigma'(t)\psi_t^* (g) + \sigma(t) \psi_t^*(\partial_t g) + \sigma(t) \psi_t^*(L_Xg)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4308471/how-to-show-partial-t-hat-g-sigmat-psi-t-g-sigmat-psi-t-pa) but there's not a clear answer.

Comment: Although I forgot the details, I still remeber the expression of Bryant  (Ricci flow solitons in dimension three with SO(3)-symmetries) is right in my opinion.

Comment: Isn't this just a missing chain rule? E.g.

$$\frac{d}{dt}\psi_t^*(g(t)) \Big|_{t = s} = \mathcal{L}_{X(s)}(g(s)) + \psi_s^*(\dot{g}(s))$$